# jQuery - get first load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, load

I have signup page in Rails where I show and hide div when the user clicks on the `Next` link. At the third step of registration, the form gets submitted and at that time default div is shown. I want to jump to another div.

How can I check whether the page has been loaded already and if so then the default div should be hidden?

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#admin_new").validationEngine();
$("#next_step_personal").click(function (e) {
    if ($('div.field_with_errors').size() > 0) {
        alert("Please correct the errors");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#personal_info").hide();
        $("#account_info").show();
        $("#subscription").hide();
    }
});
$("#billing_info").click(function (e) {
    if ($('div.field_with_errors').size() > 0) {
        alert("Please correct the errors");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#personal_info").hide();
        $("#account_info").hide();
        $("#subscription").show();
    }
});
$("#prev_billing").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#personal_info").show();
    $("#account_info").hide();
    $("#subscription").hide();
});
$('#subscription_l').click(function () {
    $('#admin_new').submit();
    $("#personal_info").hide();
    $("#account_info").hide();
    $("#subscription").hide();
    $("#purchase_code").show();
});
});
```

Comment: are you using divs as seperate forms?
can you show an example of your divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
if($('#defaultDiv').is(':visible')) {
    // jump to desired div
}
```

If your 'defaultDiv' is visible to the user, the function will be executed. You should probably hide the 'defaultDiv' as part of that function too.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
$(function(){ // -> this happens only when page has finished loading
  $(<selector_for_default_div>).hide();
})
```